# Click outside of element to hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code does this: when element `.pencil` is clicked on, it toggles the hidden element `.pencilpanel`. When clicked outside of **this** `.test` element (there are two `.test` elements), then **this** `.pencilpanel` should hide.

**However**, my problems are that:

1) When the second `.test` element is clicked on, the first `.test` element remains visible when it should be hidden. And,

2) When the first `.pencil` element is clicked on, and its corresponding `.pencilpanel` is also clicked on, it will *hide* `.pencilpanel`, when it's *supposed* to remain visible. Any element that is currently visible within `.test`, and if clicked on, **should not** be hidden, **unless** that clicked on element lies **outside** of the **current** `.test` element.

So I'm not getting why when a click is made on `.pencilpanel`, it hides it on this line `if(!$(this).closest('.test').length && $('.pencilpanel').is(":visible")) {`. And the fact that the first `.pencilpanel` remains visible when it should be hidden whenever another `.pencil` is clicked on. This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pencil').on('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent(".btsdiv").next(".fcmdiv").children(".pencilpanel").toggleClass("displayblock");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
        if (!$(this).closest('.test').length && $('.pencilpanel').is(":visible")) {
            $('.pencilpanel').removeClass("displayblock");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.pencilpanel {
    display: none;
}

.displayblock {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <div class="btsdiv">
        <div class="pencil">&#9998;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fcmdiv">
        <div class="pencilpanel">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="btsdiv">
        <div class="pencil">&#9998;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fcmdiv">
        <div class="pencilpanel">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `document.activeElement` to check before you close the panels. Please find the modified code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.pencil').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    closePanel();
    $(this).closest(".test").find(".pencilpanel").toggleClass("displayblock");
  });

  $(document).on("click", function() {
    if (document.activeElement.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
      closePanel();
  });

});


function closePanel() {
  $('.pencilpanel').removeClass("displayblock");
}
```

```css
.pencilpanel {
  display: none;
}

.displayblock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="test">
  <div class="btsdiv">
    <div class="pencil">&#9998;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fcmdiv">
    <div class="pencilpanel">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <div class="btsdiv">
    <div class="pencil">&#9998;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fcmdiv">
    <div class="pencilpanel">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What? Never knew of activeElement before. Thanks also for fixing my code and pointing out everything else I missed. Completely works now, Thank you!!

Comment: Seems good. A minor suggestion though, no need to have two document.ready handlers.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Sorry for the bother, but can activeElement be used on classnames also? Because I need to repeat this script on a classname that does not contain a textarea. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: what do you mean by class name? classname of the active element?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Yes, like if I want to target by the element's classname `.pencilpanel` for instance

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you can get it from  `document.activeElement.className`

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Sorry for being annoying again, but I'm trying the `document.activeElement.className`, but this is not working. I read the documentation and it says it only works on form elements. You know a way to target textarea's visibility by its parent's classname?

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you provide a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.pencil').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.pencilpanel').removeClass("displayblock");
    $(this).parent().siblings().children(".pencilpanel").addClass("displayblock"); 
  });

  $(".pencilpanel").click(function () {
     event.stopPropagation();          
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
     $('.pencilpanel').not(":focus").removeClass("displayblock");        
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.pencilpanel').hide();
    $('.pencil').on('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var elm=$(this).parent(".btsdiv").next(".fcmdiv").children(".pencilpanel");
        $('.pencilpanel').not(elm).hide();
        if(elm.css('display') == 'none') elm.css('display','inline-block');
        else elm.css('display','none');
    });
    
    $("*").on('click',function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if($(this).hasClass("pencil")) return;
        if($(this).hasClass("pencilpanel")) return;
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("pencilpanel")) return;
        $('.pencilpanel').hide();
    });
    
});
```

```css
.pencil {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pencil, .pencilpanel {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <div class="btsdiv">
        <div class="pencil">&#9998;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fcmdiv">
        <div class="pencilpanel">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="btsdiv">
        <div class="pencil">&#9998;</div>
     <br>
    </div>
    <div class="fcmdiv">
        <div class="pencilpanel">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```